# Как обновлять значения в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив: 
**img**
Есть два метода:
**1. getBlueImg
2. getGreenImg**
В них я получаю из некоторой бд по 5 путей к изображениям и записываю их в массив img с помощью push.

Как сделать так, чтобы при вызове одного из этих методов, в массив не добавлялось еще 5 элементов, а перезаписывались 5 уже существующих?

Comment: перед добавлением допишите `arr = []` - почистится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед вызовом метода обновить массив

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
array = []; // :D
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(arr); // [1,2,3,4,5]
arr = [6,7,8,9,0];
console.log(arr); // [6,7,8,9,0]

const arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(arr2); // [1,2,3,4,5]
arr2 = [6,7,8,9,0];
console.log(arr2); // TypeError: Assignment to constant variable
```

Как вы видете из примера выше, если вы используете *let* переменную - не надо ее занулять или очищать, просто присвойте новое значение и оно изменится.
*const* выведет ошибку, потому что нельзя менять значение константы после ее объявления.

Возможно, у вас в функции метод добавления реализовал с помощью функции concat или push. Тогда имеет смысл обнулять переменную или просто возвращать результат в виде `let images = getImage(params);`, так будет более читабельней и логичней.